# SQLAlchemy query to return all parents and only child rows matching a condition

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, pyside

I have a one to many relationship like this:

```
class Person(BASE):

    __tablename__ = 'person'
    __table_args__ = ({'sqlite_autoincrement': True})

    idperson = Column(INTEGER,
                      autoincrement=True,
                      primary_key=True,
                      nullable=False)

    lastname = Column(VARCHAR(45), index=True, nullable=False)
    firstname = Column(VARCHAR(45), index=True, nullable=False)
    persontype = Column(VARCHAR(20), default='ORPHANED', nullable=False)


class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'document'
    __table_args__ = ({'sqlite_autoincrement': True})

    iddocument = Column(INTEGER,
                        autoincrement=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        nullable=False)  
    person_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey("person.idperson"),
                       index=True,
                       nullable=False)  

    doctag = Column(Varchar(20),
                     autoincrement=True,
                     primary_key=True,
                     nullable=False nullable=False, default='Misc')  

    datesigned = Column(Date)  

    person = relationship("Person", foreign_keys=[person_id],
                          backref=backref("document", uselist=True,
                          cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
```

What is the query that will return a flat list (suitable for a grid) of one person per row with
doctag and datesigned empty unless doctag == 'charter'.
Like:

```
Smith | Harry |         |        |  
Brown | James | charter | 2/2/16 |
```

An important point with this is that I'm feeding this query to a Pyside model
that expects to refer to the attributes starting from Person. so I don't want the query based on Document.

Also the actual model has two more tables in the join, but I don't think that that is important to this question.

I'm a newb at SQLAlchemy, so my attempts have been ham fisted so far.
This has no results in document related columns.

```
    self.query = (self.datamod.session.query(Person)
                  # .join(Schoolmember)
                  # .join(Student)
                  .outerjoin(Document))
```

The documents are there in the query results, as a list, but I cant access them like that (with brackets [0]'s) because the model is basically doing a getattr to fill the Pyside view.
So I need a big flat query.
I've tried to get my head around subqueries but it isn't working so far.

I think I need a query that returns *all* Persons, plus the *first* document where the filter Document.doctag == 'charter' is true.
This used to work fine with the query above when the documents were one-to-one with the Person, but I haven't been able to adapt it for many-to-one.

In other words, can I combine the results of these two queries:

```
query(Person).all()
```

and

```
    query(Person).outerjoin(Document).filter(Document.doctag=='charter').first()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is childtype and date?

Comment: You may have seen that before I edited it. childtype became doctype, which is a string. date is an sqlalchemy DATE column (SQlite variety, a date string)  the date field doesn't matter here, it may as wll be any field.

Comment: Please post your code attempts.

Comment: I'm new to this so my attempts have been fairly random, but Ill see what I can add to the post.

Comment: Right. Well your solution is to use
[`outerjoin()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.outerjoin)
to join the tables together
and
[`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter)
with `Document.childtype == 'charter'` to filter out `Document`s that are not of type `"charter"`.

Comment: If I filter out the empty rows, won't I loose the other Person's out of the results? Added a bit more info above.

Comment: I've added some more info about what I'm trying to do.